# Getting client id and add it to metadata to a request in workbox

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have workbox setup with background sync module. Currently I wonder how to handle 2 different clients in the sync code if they do some conflicting operation, i.e creating an item with the same local id.

So in order to tell where a request came from I would need some sort of client id & I would like to add that to the request metadata.

I looked through the documentation and I didn't find anything. My workbox version is 5.1.4

Any help would be appreciated!